# CSS3 Transform rotate changes the flow

Tags: html, css, rotation, transform

I need to create a website with a background image that is overlayed with a white background color:

[image: The design]

Now the problem is, that the CSS3 Transform rotate property changes the flow of the HTML without updating said HTML's height.

To demonstrate this I appended the text a bit to create a scrollbar:
[image: Appended text forces a scrollbar]

As you can see, the page cuts off the background image, and when I remove the transform the background ends at the place it should end:
[image: Transform removed and it's all okay]

The element that generates the rotated white background is a absolute positioned div inside the main content with top and bottom 0px, left and right 100vw to make sure that when I rotate it it doesn't show any corners. The actual background image is an absolute positioned div with all sides 0px but the same can be accomplished with giving it to the HTML tag.

I do know why it creates an additional scrollbar, because of the definition stated by w3:

[W3 info about adding a scrollbar](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering)

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, the transform property does not affect the flow of the content surrounding the transformed element. However, the extent of the overflow area takes into account transformed elements. This behavior is similar to what happens when elements are offset via relative positioning. Therefore, if the value of the overflow property is scroll or auto, scrollbars will appear as needed to see content that is transformed outside the visible area.

Now my question is, why does the transformation of an (absolute) element create an additional scrollbar but not update the HTML accordingly to show a proper background (for example)? And how would I be able to properly fix this?

Answer (score 2):

maybe the use of a `background gradient` would do , it can be laid on top of background-image or within the header and footer *(image can also be split into those two)* , where content just holds a background-color.

```css
section {
  background: linear-gradient(-189deg, transparent 10em, white 10.2em, white 50%, transparent 55%), linear-gradient(351deg, transparent 10em, white 10.2em, white 50%, transparent 55%), url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/105294/pexels-photo-105294-medium.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 1020px;
  margin: auto;
  border:solid;
}

nav {
  padding: 4em 1em;
}

footer {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 3em 2em 1em ;
  text-align: right
}

aside {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 3%;
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

aside img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

article {
  padding: 1em 3%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* extra demo purpose to resize content */
  transition:0.5s;
}
article:hover {font-size:0.5em;}
```

```html
<section>
  <nav><a href="#">link</a>  <a href="#">link</a>  <a href="#">link</a>  <a href="#">link</a>  <a href="#">link</a>  <a href="#">link</a>  <a href="#">link</a> 
  </nav>
  <div>
    <aside>
      <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/139229/pexels-photo-139229-medium.jpeg" />
    </aside>
    <article>
      <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

      <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
        placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

      <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

      <ol>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
        <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
      </ol>

      <blockquote>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus
          turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
      </blockquote>
    </article>
    <footer>
      footer standing at bottom</footer>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: That would be an amazing solution, as it doesn't give the scrollbars! There are just a couple of issues. If the page is not long at all, the white background should only encapsulate the text, and not continue to the bottom. Another problem is that this solution doesn't take the menu and such into concideration. If you look at the first image you see that it runs through the middle of both the top navigation and the right side navigation.

Answer (score 1):

> However, the extent of the overflow area takes into account transformed elements.

Following this definition, is properly correct that your transform div expands the height. If you don't want the height to be expanded, you can use `overflow:hidden` on the parent element.

Also, you want the background full screen all the time, right? Then use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute` for the background div.

Comment: I cannot use overflow:hidden as it will remove the scrollbar, I want a scrollbar if the content of the page is too long. Setting the background to fixed is also not a valid solution to my problem, as I want the background image to stretch with the page, I want only the header to contain the sea, and the rest to be sand.

Comment: @ThomasvandenBulk so you want to repeat the background vertically, but only with sand?

Comment: Hmmh that does bring up the idea of just giving the HTML a background-repeat with just sand.